# AzureML: taking parameters as input

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a code R (manipulateXY.R) taking parameters X (from picklist), Y (a "not constrained" value) from a text file (parameter.txt) and producing n images.
I want to put this code as a "R script" in Azure ML, and to produce a web service pointing to that logic (manipulateXY). The question is: how can I pass parameters to the Azure code? I need it because I want a web app with the following outfit

[image]

such that I choose the X and Y and press "Run", it calls the logic in Azure ML, it takes the generated images and put them on the web-app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use web service parameters as shown here - [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-web-service-parameters](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-web-service-parameters/)/